# Leaflet inside Bootstrap col doesn't occupy full height

Tags: css, angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm using Angular and Leaflet, with the ngx-leaflet package, and I can't get my map to occupy the full height and width of the page. It works well when I define a fixed height and width, but not when I change them to 100vh, appears vertical scroll bar.

The div containing the map:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="map" leaflet [leafletOptions]="mapOptions"></div>
</div>
```

The styles applied globally:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The style applied to the map:

```
.map {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the app:

[image]

Comment: Try setting `height:100vh` instead of `height:100%` for the class `.map`

Comment: @GrzegorzT. it appears now, but I'm left with a vertical scroll bar

Comment: Can you add a print screen to your question, full site? Add this `body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; } body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: already added a sreenshot. the last suggestion didn't changed anything...

Comment: Nothing has changed because I haven't seen the whole thing :)
`height: calc(100vh - height of the blue header in px)`

Comment: that last suggestion worked just fine, thanks!